# How to access wifi in recovery mode

Tags: command-line, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 with an encrypted drive. I want to install different nvidia drivers in recovery mode. But in order to do that I need to access wifi. How do I do that? I find `iwconfig` confusing

---

By the way, when I choose `network` in safe mode I get `etc/resolv.conf no such file or directory`